# Need to execute SQL query dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, oracle11g, pycharm

I need to update name of customer using the input provided by the user. 
original_name need to be updated by new_name

```
cur.execute(''' 
CREATE TABLE customer (customerId int,customerName varchar(20),telephoneNo int,
                    addressId varchar(20), customerType varchar(20),
                    discount int, memCardType varchar(20))''')
```

I'm trying to perform this code, but it gives an error.

```
    original_name=input("Enter name to be modified: ")
    new_name=input("Enter new name of the customer: ")
    cur.execute("UPDATE customer SET customerName=new_name WHERE  customerName=original_name   ")
    print("Customer name changes successfully.")
```

Error:

```
 cur.execute("UPDATE customer SET customerName=new_name WHERE  
customerName=original_name   ")
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "ORIGINAL_NAME": invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you use a SQL cursor so I would do it like that :

```
original_name=input("Enter name to be modified: ")
new_name=input("Enter new name of the customer: ")
cur.execute("UPDATE customer SET customerName=:new_name WHERE  customerName=:cust_name",{'cust_name': original_name, 'new_name' : new_name})
print("Customer name changes successfully.")
```

The concept is simple. `:new_name` and `:cust_name` are binding parameters, in fact you told to your function you will add this parameter as variable then in

```
{'cust_name': original_name, 'new_name' : new_name}
```

You just fill those binding parameters with your variables.

Comment: its showing a error- `cur.execute("UPDATE customer SET customerName=%s WHERE  customerName=%s",(original_name,new_name))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`

Comment: I added the explanation in the answer .